# How can I change the nametag of a villager using commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to change the nametag of a villager using commands in Minecraft?

Comment: Look at the wiki. `CustomName` and `CustomNameVisible`

Comment: very weird hat you couldn't find that on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the NBT component `CustomName`

So to change name of an already existing villager you do `entitydata @e[type=villager,c=1] {CustomName:"New Name"}`

Also, to make the name always visible and not only when looked at you can add `CustomNameVisible:1b` to the NBT as well.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/data merge entity @e[type=villager,limit=1,sort=nearest] {CustomName:"\"New Name\"}`